# Stellar JS (parallax plugin) positioning issue

Tags: jquery, css, position, offset, parallax

I'm creating a parallax site with stellar js, and I'm having serious trouble with the positioning of elements within a "slide." all of my elements are perfectly aligned with the given css; however, as soon as I add a 'data-stellar-ratio' attribute to the images, their position is completely screwed up. there is no discernible pattern to the screwy offset, or I'd just adjust the css.

here's my html

```
<body>
  <div id="scrollContainer">
    <div id="scroller">

        <section data-slide="1" class="slide" id="slide1" > <!-- Home Screen -->
            <img class="part" data-stellar-ratio="1.5"  src="images/vi.svg" alt="">
            <img class="part" data-stellar-ratio="2" src="images/nyl.svg" alt="">
            <img class="part" data-stellar-ratio="3"  src="images/vibe.svg" alt="">
            <img class="part" data-stellar-ratio="2.5"  src="images/whitaker.svg" alt="">
            <img class="part" data-stellar-ratio="1"  src="images/red.svg" alt="">
        </section> <!-- END Home -->
```

Each "section.slide" is set to "position: relative;" and the child images are set to absolute. Here's my css

```
    #scroller
    {
    text-align: left;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    }
    section.slide { position:relative; width:960px; height: 728px;}
    .part { position:absolute; }

    section#slide1 {background: #f2f2f2; width:100%;}
    section#slide1 .part:first-child  { width:524px; left:-297px; top:715px; } /* vi */
    section#slide1 .part:nth-child(2) { width:780px; left:159px; top:1072px; /*bottom:-344px;*/} /* nyl */
    section#slide1 .part:nth-child(3) { width:395px; left:357px; top: 525px; /*bottom:203px;*/ } /*vibe*/
    section#slide1 .part:nth-child(4) { width:641px; left:599px; top: 590px; /*bottom:138px;*/ } /*whitaker*/
    section#slide1 .part:nth-child(5) { width:424px; left:28px; top: 842px; /*bottom:-114px;*/ } /*red*/
```

Does anyone know an appropriate solution? Thanks for any help!! I've been at it for 3 hours, and have found no solution by trial, nor have I found one online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant remember for sure, but i think i solved this just by adding **horizontalScrolling:false**.

```
$.stellar({
    horizontalScrolling:false
    // other options...
});
```

Comment: Much appreciated, man. I ended up trying that, and it worked. I eventually figured this out. Hopefully others will find the post helpful!